# Cannot compile ToBooleanBiFunction.java

Tags: java

I want to compile a java project that ask for others as symbol not found.
This led me to a class called ToBoleanbeFunction. I am stuck there a it try to import applyAsBollean that I compiled (is saved under the Tomcat lib directory). But my web application seem not findind it thougt does not complain about the import.

```
package org.apache.commons.lang3.function;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ToBooleanBiFunction {
boolean applyAsBoolean(T t, U u);
}
```

When compiling, i complain that java doesnt find symbols T an U.
Anny ideas?

Comment: The compiler is right: You did not declare `T` nor `U`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They need to be declared as generic types in the signature of the interface:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ToBooleanBiFunction<T, U> {
    boolean applyAsBoolean(T t, U u);
}
```

This is because `ToBooleanBiFunction<String, String>`, for example, is fundamentally different from `ToBooleanBiFunction<String, Integer>`.